# MySQL - Select current and next 11 month

Tags: mysql, timestamp

My Table `items` has a `date_due` date that is storing timestamps.
I try to select every record that is from the current Month and the next 11 month (one year)

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE MONTH(date_due) BETWEEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(CURRENT_DATE() INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
```

but unfortunately this is not working. Maybe someone can help?

Here is a Fiddle until I got it working:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16bd5/5

What is not working: I do not know how to limit the records to "next 11 month from today including todays Month"

Comment: Provide table structure and example data place it on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com.. Also make a ascii (text formatted) text with expected output based on the example data.

Comment: please elaborate, **what is not working**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong by comparing only months. You also need to add year in where.

Try below query

```
SELECT * FROM item 
WHERE (YEAR(date_due)>YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) OR (YEAR(date_due)>=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(date_due)>=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))) 
AND (YEAR(date_due)<YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)) OR (YEAR(date_due)<=YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)) AND MONTH(date_due)<=MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH))))
```